# How to group by the records to a list of category items

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a record from my stored procedure and bound the data to the `AppCategoryDataModel`.

Now, I want to iterate that data and create a list of the `List<CategoryData>`, adding DetailId,  Title, and Description as a list, grouped by `AppCategoryId`

```
public class AppCategoryDataModel
{
    public Nullable<int> AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DetailId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsShow { get; set; }
}
```

What i have tried:

```
 var res = db.Database.SqlQuery<AppCategoryDataModel>($"call getAppCategoryData({memberId}, {unitId}, {taxId})")
                    .Select(z => new FirstLevelCategory
                    {
                        AppCategoryId = z.AppCategoryId.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        AppCategoryName = z.AppCategoryName,
                        IsShow = z.IsShow,
                        CategoryData = ??
                    }).ToList();
```

The `FirstLevelCategory`properties are:

```
public class FirstLevelCategory
{
    public int AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool? IsShow { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Details>CategoryData { get; set; }   
}
```

How can I do that using LINQ and not by using `group by` clause ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Group by?

Comment: there are a lot of fields to select, and using group by I think it will create a query more complex.

Comment: First make it work, then optimize iff necessary. Also don't underestimate the query provider's translation capabilities

Comment: GroupBy by AppCategoryId, AppCategoryName, IsShow, is what you need.

Comment: Can you help with an example? @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: What's in a Detail? Where did you get it from? The original object only has DetailId? Does it mean you want a list of detailId per appId and then you will look up the Detail separately, using the DetailId, if someone selected the grouped appId in the UI?

Comment: all the details come directly from the stored procedure. yes `want a list of detailed per appId `. i need to return the list to the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by grouping and grouping is right way here

```cs
var res = db.Database.SqlQuery<AppCategoryDataModel>($"call getAppCategoryData({memberId}, {unitId}, {taxId})")
    .GroupBy(x => new { AppCategoryId, AppCategoryName, IsShow })
    .Select(z => new FirstLevelCategory
    {
        AppCategoryId = z.Key.AppCategoryId,
        AppCategoryName = z.Key.AppCategoryName,
        IsShow = z.Key.IsShow,
        CategoryData = z.Select(x => new Detail 
        [
            DetailId = x.DetailId,
            Title = x.Title,
            Description = x.Description
        ])
        .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```